# doesn't execute javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```js
function estimate(Genre, Amount) {
            var estimated;
            
            if(Genre == "Add Genre ") {
                estimated = Amount *  11111;
                price.value  = estimated;
            } else if (Genre == "Add Topic") {
                estimated = Amount * 11111;
                price.value  = estimated;
            } 
        }

        var initAmount = 1;
        var Genre;
        var selected = document.getElementById("selected")
        var amount = document.getElementById("amount")
        var price =  document.getElementById("price");

        amount.addEventListener("change", function(){
            Amount = this.value;
            Amount = parseInt(Amount);
            estimate(Genre, Amount);
        });

        selected.addEventListener("change", function(){
            console.log('Selected Genre:', Genre);
            Genre = this.value;
            estimate(Genre, Amount);
        });
```

```html
<form action="/advertisers/9/checkouts" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="R9bTv4vpV+zi31JfM0F/QjUQbVJzf8S4jneBx46TWS8lJ7JA9luW+WBqiAEXQRr+3UhrwqXeiiv/xm61ceInkQ==" autocomplete="off">



<div class="field col-12">
   <br>
 <select id="selected" class="col-12 border rounded" name="order_form[ad_type]"><option value="Choose Type">Choose Type</option>
<option value="Add Genre">Add Genre</option>
<option value="Add Topic">Add Topic</option></select><br>
</div>


<div class="field col-12">
   <label for="order_form_amount">Amount</label><br>
   <input value="1" id="amount" class="col-12" min="1" max="20" type="number" name="order_form[amount]"><br>
</div>

<div class="field col-12">
   <label for="order_form_price">Price</label><br>
   <input readonly="readonly" id="price" class="col-12" type="text" name="order_form[price]"><br>
</div>

<div class="field col-12">

<input value="9" class="col-12" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="order_form[advertiser_id]" id="order_form_advertiser_id">

</div>



<div class="actions col-12 ">

   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="checkout" class="site-btn mb-sm-1" data-disable-with="checkout">
   <br>
</div>



</form>
```

I want to implement prototype for calculate system in javascript with rails
Seemingly it's not wrong code but doesn't execute it
this code attempt to get html elements
then caluculate value for each types
I checked process with console.log
so that I noticed that I  couldn't go  to in  the if state
could you like to help me?

```
estimate js 

function estimate(Genre, Amount) {
var estimated;

if(Genre == "Add Genre ") {

    estimated = Amount *  11111;
    price.value  = estimated;
  
} else if (Genre == "Add Topic") {

    estimated = Amount * 11111;
    price.value  = estimated;
   
   } 
  

}

export default estimate;

application js 

 var initAmount = 1;
 var Genre;
 //here are tags
 var selected = document.getElementById("selected")
 var amount = document.getElementById("amount")
 var price =  document.getElementById("price");
//
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {

   amount.addEventListener("change", function(){
   Amount = this.value;
   Amount = parseInt(selectedAmount);
   estimate(Genre, Amount);
 }

selected.addEventListener("change", function(){
  console.log('Selected Genre:', Genre);
  Genre = this.value;
  estimate(Genre, Amount);


 });
 }

_form.hrml.erb





    <%= form_with model: @order, url: checkouts_path  ,remote: true  do  |f|  %>


  // these elements are I want to get it in javascript 
   <div class ="field col-12">
    <% f.label :ad_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :ad_type,  ["Choose Type",    t("layout.add_genre"), 
    t("layout.add_topic") ], {}, {id: "selected"} %><br />
</div>


   <div class ="field col-12">
   <%= f.label :amount %><br />
   <%= f.number_field :amount,value: 1, id: "amount" %><br />
   </div>

     <div class ="field col-12">
      <%= f.label :price %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :price ,readonly: true,id: "price"%><br />
      </div>

 //

   <div class="actions col-12 ">
    <%= f.submit "checkout", class: "site-btn mb-sm-1" %>
   </br>
   </div>
    <% end %>
```

locales en.yml

```
en:
 layout: 
   add_genre: Add Genre
   add_topic: Add Topic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the rendered HTML. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor to create a *stack snippet*. With that we can run your code here on the page and check for errors.

Comment: Where are the Javascript file script tags relative to your form?

Comment: I appreciate you all,
I edited code I'd like you to check it please?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to cover here.

1. Always define a variable with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Defining a variable without these keywords will result in the variable being defined as a property on the `window` object. So doing `Amount = this.value`, will effectively be `window.Amount = this.value`. `const` and `let` were introduced later in JS and are *block scoped*, meaning that unlike `var` they will only exist between the current block `{ }` that they're in.
2. Keep your functions simple/pure. The function here is called `estimate`, which I would expect that it would make an estimation and give me that result. Introducing *side-effects* like updating the `price` element could cause confusion.
3. Both event listener [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) both need the `type` and `amount` values for the `estimate` function. So in both cases you'll need to access the `value` of the `typeSelector` and `amountInput` fields.

I've renamed some variables to adhere to JS coding conventions. Things like Capitalized variables such as `Amount` imply that it is a constructable function which you should use like so: `const amountInstance = new Amount();`

```js
function estimate(type, amount) {
  if (type == "add-genre") {
    return amount * 11111;
  } else if (type == "add-topic") {
    return amount * 22222;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

const typeSelector = document.getElementById("type")
const amountInput = document.getElementById("amount")
const priceInput = document.getElementById("price");

typeSelector.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const type = typeSelector.value;
  const amount = amountInput.value;
  priceInput.value = estimate(type, amount);
});

amountInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const amount = amountInput.value;
  const type = typeSelector.value;
  priceInput.value = estimate(type, amount);
});
```

```html
<form action="/advertisers/9/checkouts" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="R9bTv4vpV+zi31JfM0F/QjUQbVJzf8S4jneBx46TWS8lJ7JA9luW+WBqiAEXQRr+3UhrwqXeiiv/xm61ceInkQ==" autocomplete="off">



  <div class="field col-12">
    <br>
    <select id="type" class="col-12 border rounded" name="order_form[ad_type]">
      <option value="Choose Type">Choose Type</option>
      <option value="add-genre">Add Genre</option>
      <option value="add-topic">Add Topic</option>
    </select><br>
  </div>


  <div class="field col-12">
    <label for="order_form_amount">Amount</label><br>
    <input value="1" id="amount" class="col-12" min="1" max="20" type="number" name="order_form[amount]"><br>
  </div>

  <div class="field col-12">
    <label for="order_form_price">Price</label><br>
    <input readonly="readonly" id="price" class="col-12" type="text" name="order_form[price]"><br>
  </div>

  <div class="field col-12">

    <input value="9" class="col-12" autocomplete="off" type="hidden" name="order_form[advertiser_id]" id="order_form_advertiser_id">

  </div>



  <div class="actions col-12 ">

    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="checkout" class="site-btn mb-sm-1" data-disable-with="checkout">
    <br>
  </div>



</form>
```